# "if an int can hold all values of the original type then the value is converted to int , else to unsigned int"--What it means?

Tags: c, int, type-conversion, expression, unsigned-integer

The above line is about implicit integral promotions/conversions in C, taken from the book by Mike Banahan [Section 2.8.1.1 (Link)](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter2/expressions_and_arithmetic.html). Here's what the exact paragraph is:

> No arithmetic is done by C at a precision shorter than int, so these conversions are implied almost whenever you use one of the objects listed below in an expression. The conversion is defined as follows:
>
> Whenever a short or a char (or a bitfield or enumeration type which we
>   haven't met yet) has the integral promotions applied
>
> - **if an int can hold all of the values of the original type then the
>     value is converted to int**
> - **otherwise, the conversion will be to unsigned int**

Here are my confusions about the part in bold. Please clear these:

- Isn't the "otherwise" part redundant? Shouldn't all **short** or **char** types fit into an **int** by default given that **int** is larger than either in size? How does the question of a **short** not fitting into an **int** and requiring an **unsigned int** even arise?
- How is the "otherwise" part valid–If a negative short integer is converted implicitly to unsigned int, won't its value change?

Though I was tempted to dismiss it as trivial and move on, I felt getting a proper explanation would be better. Thank you.

Comment: Int can hold all values of short, but not necessarily all values of unsigned short.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `int` type (according to the C standard) does not have to be larger than a `short`.  An `int` must only "not be shorter" than a `short`. They could both be 16 bits, for example.  In that case, it is possible to have an `unsigned short` value that cannot fit into an `int`.

(The Wikipedia page on [C data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types) is pretty revealing.)

Comment: Add a reference to the C specification to improve your answer.